# How Can We Stop Our Widgets From Dying Under Heavy Load?

Tags: php, load, session-variables

I've inherited a php/js project that creates audio-playing widgets.  The requirement is really that they be able to stand up to some pretty heavy load at "peak times": when a new track is first announced there may be a lot of people rushing to play it at once.

Unfortunately, the widgets tend to do pretty badly under such stressful conditions.  We had considered that saving and looking up an access key in a SQLite database might have been causing fatal errors due to locking.  Experimentally I changed the access keys to be stored in session variables, but I'm now worried this may just be creating a new kind of bottleneck: does every request have to wait for the session to free up before it can go ahead?

I downloaded Pylot and did some basic load tests: it doesn't take many agents trying to access the same widget to make it glitchy or completely unusable, maybe 10 or 20.  Ideally we'd like to be able to handle a considerably greater volume of traffic than this.  What strategies can I sensibly adopt to be able to field many times more requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PHP file-based session will lock the session file until the script exits, or you call session_write_close(). You can do a quick `session_start(); session_write_close()`. The $_SESSION array will still be available, but any subsequent changes will NOT be written to disk, as PHP has been told the session is closed.

Comment: I have session_start() at the beginning of the relevant files, I don't have any session_write_close() happening yet.  So I should open and close the session before and after writing the variable(s), and then again before and after reading?

Comment: Reading you can do anytime after calling session_start(). And keep reading after session_close. Closing the session doesn't trash $_SESSION, it just tells PHP to write it out to disk now (and not write it out again when the script exits). If you do make changes to the session later in a script, you can surround the critical parts with a _start/_write_close pair, or just do that once before the script would otherwise exit - no point in doing multiple open/close cycles if you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Store your session into a database that does only locking while wrtiing on the concrete session id (primary key that is) in a database that is supporting [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control), like MySQL and the InnoDB backend. You can further optimize this by improving the file-system beneath it.

This done you might run into race-conditions but not into lockings. Have fun!